# How to select radio button in Selenium WebDriver when locator id is different in each page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I need to select the first radio button for the field "Product" in first tab of my web page. Then script will move to second tab in same URL. In second tab also, the first radio button needs to be selected. The problem is that id of radio button is different in each tab and i am finding it hard to locate this element. id locator, css locater, xpath etc are different in each tab for each radio button. Please help

Here is my code.

```html
WebElement productRadio = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']"));
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(productRadio));
Thread.sleep(5000);
                  
     
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
boolean str2 = medicalproductRadio.isSelected();
     
if (str2)
    { System.out.println("Radio button already selected!"); }

else
    {
 
     Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
     actions.moveToElement(productRadio).click().perform();
     System.out.println("Radio Button selected by Test Script");
    }
```

Since this is the first radio button, i tried to use the xpath `//input[@type='radio']`

But script is not selecting the radio button and i am getting error message,

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:
>   waiting for element to be clickable

Here is Source code

```html
<script id="SelectTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <div class="{{>~getCssClass(~layout,null,true)}}">
        <label class="radio-label-align-middle" for="{{>Name}}" {{if Visible === true}} style='display:block;' {{else}} style='display:none;' {{/if}}>
            {{>Label}}
            {{if ~hasRequiredValidation(FullName) }}
            <em>*</em>
            {{/if}}
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="{{>~getCssClass(~layout)}} select-wrapper"  {{if Visible === true}} style='display:block;' {{else}} style='display:none;' {{/if}}>
        {{if IsMultiline === true}}
        <select id='{{>Name}}{{:~getFormInstanceId()}}' name='{{>Name}}{{:~getFormInstanceId()}}' customrule='{{>HasCustomRule}}' data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title='{{>HelpText}}'
                class='form-control multi-select {{if Enabled === false}} disabled {{/if}}'
                {{if Visible === true}} style='display:block;' {{else}} style='display:none;' {{/if}}
                {{if Enabled === false}} disabled="disabled" {{/if}}
                multiple='multiple' data-link='{{>FullName}}' data-journal='{{>FullName}}'>
            {{else}}
            <select id='{{>Name}}{{:~getFormInstanceId()}}' name='{{>Name}}{{:~getFormInstanceId()}}' customrule='{{>HasCustomRule}}' data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title='{{>HelpText}}'
                    class='form-control hastooltip {{if Enabled === false}} disabled {{/if}}'
                    {{if Visible === true}} style='display:block;' {{else}} style='display:none;' {{/if}}
                    {{if Enabled === false}} disabled="disabled" {{/if}}
                    data-link='{{>FullName}}' data-journal='{{>FullName}}'>
                <option value="[Select One]">[Select One]</option>
                {{/if}}

                {{for ~sortDropDownItems(Items,IsSortRequired) ~defaultValue=DefaultValue}}
                {{if ~defaultValue === ItemValue}}
                <option value="{{>ItemValue}}" selected>{{>ItemText}}</option>
                {{else}}
                <option value="{{>ItemValue}}">{{>ItemText}}</option>
                {{/if}}
                {{/for}}
            </select>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Some hints: Don't use `Thread.sleep(5000)`, use `WebDriverWait`. Remove the sleep and maybe increase the timeout for waiting for the element. The exception message says: The element is there, but not clickable. If the ID of an element is not stable, use a more specific locator (either CSS or Xpath) based on surrounding elements. Edit your question and add some relevant HTML snippets and the full stack strace.

Comment: `//input[@type='radio']` would get the very first element matching the xpath. So when you navigate to the second tab on your page, the xpath points to the radio button on the first tab which isn't clickable for obvious reasons. Modifying the xpath such that it takes into consideration the tab you are on may help. Post the relevant source code.

Comment: Thats the catch. For each tab, this radio button has a different id and xpath. So i am unable to locate this radio button through my script. Source Code updated in question. This is the first radio button in every tab. That is why i tried to locate using  //input[@type='radio']